# Getting n/w coordinates from google maps api

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, gps

I currently get the latitude and longitude from

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
```

I then call the results into a text box:

```
function showPosition(position)
{
     $('input[name="coordinates"]').val(position.coords.x + ", " + position.coords.y);
}
```

But what i'd like is the position to be returned as **51°56'51.48"N0°16'30.13"W**

Is there a way to do this on the fly?

many thanks in advance!
K

Comment: You haven't said what is currently displayed.

Comment: How about [this](http://isabelcastillo.com/convert-latitude-longitude-decimal-degrees)?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link posted by @TimVermaelen above ...

```
function dd2dms(lat, lng) {
    /* 
     * Convert (numbers) lat,lng to (string) degrees°minutes'seconds"
     * Sample output string: 51°56'51.48"N0°16'30.13"W
     */ 
    var convertLat = Math.abs(lat);
    var LatDeg = Math.floor(convertLat);
    var LatMin = Math.floor((convertLat - LatDeg) * 60);
    var LatSec = ((convertLat - LatDeg - LatMin/60) * 3600).toFixed(2);
    var LatCardinal = ((lat > 0) ? "N" : "S");

    var convertLng = Math.abs(lng);
    var LngDeg = Math.floor(convertLng);
    var LngMin = Math.floor((convertLng - LngDeg) * 60);
    var LngSec = ((convertLng - LngDeg - LngMin/60) * 3600).toFixed(2);
    var LngCardinal = ((lng > 0) ? "E" : "W");

    return LatDeg + '&deg;' + LatMin + "&#039;" + LatSec + '&quot;' + LatCardinal + 
        LngDeg + '&deg;' + LngMin + "&#039;" + LngSec + '' + LngCardinal;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vvekveLd/)**